# Error in traversing a doubly linked list when similar conditions are applied

Tags: doubly-linked-list

I have been given a sorted doubly linked list and am to insert a new node such that it remains sorted.

I was using this method to traverse the list

```
while(temp->next)
{
    if(temp->next->data <= newnode->data)
    {
        temp=temp->next;
    }
}
```

But this doesn't seem to work but when I used this

```
while(temp-next && temp->next->data <= newnode->data)
{
   temp=temp->next;
}
```

I didn't suffer from any errors.

I'm still in the process of learning and I'm unable to find what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: whats the error in first case?

Comment: I don't get any response on stdout and a 'terminated due to timeout' compiler message.